# values not getting autopopulate from visualforcepage

Tags: url, forcenavigatetourl

There is if-else condition added to identify wheter it is lex or classic. In class there is one get;set; public field

```
 urlString = '/lightning/o/Asset_perofrma__c/new?useRecordTypeCheck=1&defaultFieldValues=Contact__c='+clist.Id+'&Account_Name__c='+Acc.ownerId;
```

above string only contact id is prepopulating but not account ownerid and if i swap first i use account and then contact then account ownerid is prepopluation in lightning. how to prepopulate contact lookup id and account lookup ownerid.

in vfpage below code is written

```
    sforce.one.navigateToURL(urlString);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally issue got resolved, instead of & sign we have to use ,(comma)

```
urlString = '/lightning/o/Asset_perofrma__c/new?useRecordTypeCheck=1&defaultFieldValues=Contact__c='+clist.Id+',Account_Name__c='+Acc.ownerId;
```